# Github - hide issues created by admin / internally

Tags: github

Just started using GitHub and I searched for user permissions but couldn't find the answer.  Is there a way I can hide issues from the public that are created internally or mark issues as private?   I could create a new private and/or public repo for the same project but wondered if there is a better way to handle this?